# id for MAX value

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id, uid, MAX(a) FROM table GROUP BY uid
```

Now, the id is from a random/first row.

How do I get id for the maximum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, uid from table1 where a=(select max(a) from table1)
```

Of course, this will fail if you have multiple max values that are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
SELECT id, uid, a FROM table1 ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the maximum value for id just use Max(id).

```
SELECT MAX(id), uid, MAX(a) from table GROUP BY uid;
```

Comment: This will return the max ID and the max a, which could well be in two different rows.